# Error while importing one file into another in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using import while importing some functions from my practice.js file into different.js file.

```
practice.js file:-

function sum(x,y){
    return x+y;
}

const pi = 3.14;

module.exports = {
    sum : sum,
    pi:pi
};
```

different.js file:-

```
import {sum,pi} from "./practice.js";

console.log("2 pie: "+sum(pi,pi));
```

Now when I am using require, the output is proper and no error is given.
When I am using import, there is this following error:-

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

I have asked my colleagues and they told me that this is about ES6 and Babel is not configured in your system.

But I am not sure how to proceed with this. Can anybody please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your main file (different.js) to different.mjs.
Rename your practice.js file to practice.mjs and make it look like this:

```
function sum(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

const pi = 3.14;

export {sum, pi};
```

Then run `node --experimental-modules different.mjs` to run Node with it's experimental module loader.

You can read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)